# Is there an Oracle's equivalent of MySQL's show table command?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know it is possible to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(table_name) 
  FROM all_tab_cols
```

Would there be a better way in Oracle to show table, i.e. MySQL's `show table`; command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you require full structure you may use

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'MY_TABLE_NAME' ) FROM DUAL;
```

see more syntax from [Reference](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_metadata.html)

Comment: Also, in sqlplus you can try "describe <owner>.<table_name>;"

Comment: @Pop: `DESCRIBE` isn't SQLPLus specific, and it only provides information on one table, not all the tables in a database and/or schema

Comment: To view result as String of characters not CLOB
We can use
SELECT `to_char`(dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'MY_TABLE_NAME' )) FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 4):

Try `describe table <table-name>` in SQL*Plus. It does all the fetching and nice formatting. Works with tables, but also procedures, triggers, constraints, etc (just use different keywords).

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
select * from user_tables;
```

To get basic stuff. To get just the tablenames:

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

Comment: `user_tables` is only the tables your user has access to -- `all_tab` does not have that restriction.

Comment: user_tables lists the tables from the users own schema. all_tables lists alle the tables the user is granted access to. If the user has the dba role you can also use dba_tables to list all tables in all schemas.

Answer (score 1):

```
describe <table-name>
```

in SQL*Plus

Answer (score 0):

Off course this depends on your use. Do you need the information in a program or do you want to have a look at the table structure yourself? Many tools will give you a view of the table structure including: PLSQL developer, Toad for Oracle, SQLDeveloper. If you want to use the table structure in a query better resort to the Oracle data dictionary views (user_..., all_..., dba_...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes to all the tables that belong to your current user/schema run the below Query in Oracle database:-

`SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES;`.